# Python: Function returning highest value in list without max()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a function that takes a list of numbers as the parameter and returns the largest number in the list without using `max()`.

I've tried:

```
def highestNumber(l):
  myMax = 0
  if myMax < l:
    return myMax

  return l


print highestNumber ([77,48,19,17,93,90])
```

...and a few other things that I can't remember. I just need to understand how to loop over elements in a list.

Comment: Asking for external resources (such as a tutorial) is specifically off-topic here.

Comment: @rio5029: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Comment: btw, how on earth did you come up with that code in the first place? I see no logic there whatsoever. I mean... Python reads almost like English... if you read your code out loud, don't you feel that it's completely nonsensical?

Comment: Yeah, that was the initial code I started with that I just whipped out then started modifying it. I just couldn't remember all the different modifications. I've been trying to teach myself Python for the past few weeks and it's clearly not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def highestNumber(l):
    myMax = l[0]
    for num in l:
        if myMax < num:
            myMax = num
    return myMax


print highestNumber ([77,48,19,17,93,90])
```

**Output**

```
93
```

Or You can do something like this

```
def highestNumber(l):
    return sorted(l)[-1]
```

Or

```
def highestNumber(l):
    l.sort()
    return l[-1]
```

Comment: What if the list is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over all values to determine the maximum; keep track of the maximum *so far* and return that after completing the loop:

```
def highestNumber(l):
    myMax = float('-inf')
    for i in l:
        if i > myMax:
            myMax = i
    return myMax
```

Here, `float('-inf')` is a number guaranteed to be lower than *any other number*, making it a great starting point.

The `for` construct takes care of all the looping; you do that directly over the elements of `l`, `i` is assigned each element of the sequence, one by one.

Your code forgets to loop, tests the whole list against `0` and returns the whole list if the test failed.

Answer (score 0):

function to find maximum in a list without using predefined functions

```
def max_len_list(temp):
    i=1
    for each in temp:
        while i < max_len:
            comp=each;
            if comp > temp[i]:
                i=i+1;
            elif temp[i] > comp:
                comp=temp[i];
                i=i+1
        return comp
list1 = [];
max_len=3;
try:
    while len(list1) < max_len :
        no = int(input("enter a number\n"));
        list1.append(no);
except:
    print "enter number not string"
max_no=max_len_list(list1);
print max_no
```

Comment: A couple things I'd suggest. This being an old question, its certainly valuable to follow up if you have the answer - thank you. I'd suggest adding code formatting to your answer. There is a wysiwyg above the form, or you can use markdown http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I disagree with @LessQuesar in this case. New answers are only useful if they add something that hasn't been said in all the other answers. New answers to low-quality questions, that have several answers already - those are not valuable.