# Trying to make a function which results largest number in the list

Tags: python

Hi I am a beginner in Python, and I am trying to make a function which shows me the largest element in the list. Where I am going wrong?

```
l = [2,6,9,7,41,4]

def getmax(l):
    assume = l[0]
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if l[0] > l[i]:
            assume = l[0]
        else:
            assume = l[i]
    return assume

print(getmax(l))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `l[0]` in the `if` and `assume = l[0]`. This way you're always comparing/setting against the first index. Anyway, why not just use the [`max`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list) function?

Comment: What evidence do you have that you are doing anything wrong, and why won't you share?

Comment: @0stone0 thanks a lot man!! I feel so dumb now :')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Function returning highest value in list without max()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19469136/6045800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want, I believe:

```
l = [2,6,9,7,41,4]

def getmax(l):
    assume = l[0]
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if l[i] > assume:
            assume = l[i]
    return assume

print(getmax(l))
```

Output:

```
41
```

Comment: I believe what they *really* want is `max(l)` xD

Comment: @Tomerikoo Wish I could use that :p. Thank you @constantstranger! Learning Python rn and stackoverflow community feels like a heaven for newbies like me :))

Comment: @John Paul Glad to hear this was useful. Do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: @constantstranger Thanks, I am done with that question, any suggestions/books/websites for practicing questions could be helpful?

Comment: @John Paul For books and tutorials you could start here: <https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks> and <https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers>.

Answer (score 0):

hey of course you can use the builtin max function, but that won't be perfect for the purpose.

Your problem is that you always compare against the l[0] element instead of "assume" :).

```
def getmax(l: list) -> int:
    assume = l[0]
    for number in l[1:]
         if number > assume:
             assume = number
    return assume
```

As you see, you don't need the else branch, as the number stays the same with same numbers or a lower number :).

The l[1:] might be confusing, but it means: Take everythin from iterable "l" but skip until the first element.

Comment: *"Take everythin from iterable "l" but skip until the first element."* - that is actually confusing... I think it simply means take everything from the second element to the end

Comment: `l[1:]` actually means "create a copy of `l` omitting the first element". It does not just skip the first element in iteration.

Comment: Hi @loki.dev can you explain me a bit about this line `(l: list) -> int:`?

Comment: Hey @JohnPaul - Yes. This is optional typing. It is there to make sure we now what each of these variables contain. With tools like mypy you can check that everything works as intended :)